# How to resolve “Cannot create a temporary directory ?” (Pynacl)

Tags: 16.04, pip, arm

I'm installing Pynacl on Ubuntu 16.04 where it reaches a point where it throws error I haven't found any info about in search engine:

[image]

I get the error output after running:
`pip3 install --user paramiko`

How do I resolve this ?

Comment: please don't post pictures of text, add the (full) text instead. Also make sure to include the command that you issued.

Comment: I added the command to the post.